# How to colorize image from bottom to top over time in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm trying to think of the best way to achieve the effect shown in the image below:
[image]

Basically, I have a callback that gives me the download progress and I need to colorize an imageview from bottom to top. I've been thinking about using two imageviews on top of each other and applying a mask to one of them to conceal it. But perhaps there is a better way of colorizing just one image view? What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: Don't grow the bottom image; place a mask over the original image and then pull the mask's bottom edge towards the top to reveal the original image underneath.

Comment: Yep, that was exactly what I had in mind but on Android you can apply a grayscale mask to a single image and I was wondering whether that was possible on iOS too.